# Traefik not showing any providers in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I'm tring to add sticky session on Docker Swarm and I first started to deploy the backend and the traefik containers, but the traefik dashboard isn't showing any providers

```
loadbalancer:
    image: registry.fif.tech/traefik:latest
    command: --docker \
      --docker.swarmmode \
      --docker.watch \
      --docker.exposedbydefault=false \
      --web \
      --entryPoints="Name:http Address::8001" \
      --defaultentrypoints="http" \
      --checknewversion=false \
      --loglevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
      - 9090:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        delay: 2s
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - omni-net

  web-desktop:
    image: 'registry.fif.tech/omnichannel2-webdesktop:${TAG}'
    command: dockerize -wait http://172.17.0.1:4001/ora-cmm-workflow-executor/PreProcessService?wsdl catalina.sh run
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        failure_action: continue
        order: start-first
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    ports:
      - '9999:8080'
    environment:
      - TZ='${TZ}'
    extra_hosts:
      - "webdesktop:127.0.0.1"
      - "cmm-server-jms:${CMM_JMS_SERVER_IP}"
      - "techlog-server-jms:${TECHLOG_JMS_SERVER_IP}"
    depends_on:
      - "workflow"
      - "redis-server"
    secrets:
      - DBMetadata
      - DBSecuencial
      - Desktop
      - DesktopRedis
      - DesktopKey
    volumes: 
      - /logs-pool/tomcat:/cyberbank/logs
    configs:
      - source: recaptcha_config
        target: /cyberbank/ebanking/v2/config/recaptcha.properties
    logging:
      driver: none
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail http://localhost:8080/Techbank/sso || exit 1"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 26
      start_period: 2m
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=omnichannel2_omni-net"
      - "traefik.port=9999"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/Techbank;"
      - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.sticky=true"
    networks:
      - omni-net
```

There is any problem on the stack definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swarm mode the traefik labels must be declared on the service instead of the container, so move your labels to the deploy section.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#labels-1